# Header Location not redirecting after killing Session

Tags: php

I realise this has been asked before but i have gone over the previous questions to no avail.

I am getting no errors, just a blank page when I logout and kill the session. The session dies but no redirect :(

Here is the include for logout

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.

session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
);
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();

if(PHP_SESSION_NONE === true){

//i added this conditional statement as a last ditch, there was no if statement to begin with just a simple redirect, neither work.     

header("Locaction: index.php");
}
?>
```

Here is my form code.

```
<form action="endSession.php" method="post" id="end_session">
<button type="submit" name="end_session" id="end_button">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please check your spelling `header("Locaction: index.php");` it is `Locaction` but should be `Location`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling mistake in header. It's `Location` not `Locaction`.

It should be like  : `header("Location: index.php");`

Please refer this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 2):

PHP_SESSION_NONE is only a constant.

You have to check the session status.

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've misspelled `Location`:

```
//Your spelling
header("Locaction: index.php");

//Correct spelling
header("Location: index.php");
```

*[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)*

---

Also, `PHP_SESSION_NONE` is, as far as I can see, being used incorrectly. It is the return value of `session_status()`, so you should use it like so:

```
if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE){ //...
```

Although better practice would be:

```
if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){ //...
```

*[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php)*

Answer (score 1):

You'll typed `Location` as `Locaction`.

Please check your error messages. You can refer to this post on how to check for error messages: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php).

Alternatively, you can try using a online syntax checker: http://phpcodechecker.com, but enabling it in your server is still the best way.

Comment: I didn't get any error messages. I'm fairly new to PHP, i'll google enabling it.

Comment: @red_starz Edited answer on how to enable error checker

Comment: Thanks :) Very helpful!